# Increment array index for input

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, increment

I am looking the user to input a name to be entered into the array, the program will then give the option to enter another name so I want the second name to be entered into the next index in the array. At the moment I can only either get the name to populate all index's of the array or else just the first which it keeps overwriting.

The code below is writing it to all index's:

```
while (nameArrayCount < 10) {
  studentNamesArray[nameArrayCount] = studentName;
  nameArrayCount++;
}
```

I under stand why it does this as `nameArraycount` is being incremented each time and it fits the condition of the statement but I don't know how I can get it to exit the `while` loop and increment the value. If I try the following code the program hangs after a name is inputted - which I'm assuming is due to it forever incrementing `nameArrayCount`?

```
while (nameArrayCount < 10) {
  studentNamesArray[nameArrayCount] = studentName;
}
nameArrayCount++;
```

How can I get the program to only enter a new index if that condition is true but to then increment `nameArraycount` and exit the while loop? (If the user then selects the option to enter another name I want to check less than 10 has been entered)

I have tried using an `if` statement but I can only get it to populate the first index in the array which it keeps overwriting if the user enters a second name.

Comment: You're only giving a portion of the code. Is the actual input reading before this code? If so, it's fundamentally broken as no new data will be read during the loop, making it use the same string over and over.

Comment: The input reading is indeed before the code shown. Would it be better then to pass the inputted values to a separate function to insert them into the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is the solution that I used in case anyone else is doing something similar, I will say though that if you have a choice you should definitly follow the answer gave by @Chris.

String[] studentNamesArray = new String[10];

int nameArrayCount = 0;

String studentName;

```
    if (nameArrayCount < 10) {
      System.out.println("Enter the student's name in the following format - surname, forename: ");
      studentName = input.next();
      studentNamesArray[nameArrayCount] = studentName;
      nameArrayCount = nameArrayCount + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really avoid doing it like this, and take an OOP approach instead.

```
public class Student
{
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;

    public Student(String firstName, String secondName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName; 
    }
}
```

Then you can simply create an array of type `Student`, and populate it as you want.

**Example**

```
Student[] students = new Student[10];
int position = 0;

String firstName = scanner.readLine();
String secondName = scanner.readLine();

students[position++] = new Student(firstName, secondName);
```

And even simpler would be to use a `List` implementation.

**Example**

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
String firstName = scanner.readLine();
String secondName = scanner.readLine();
students.add(new Student(firstName, secondName));
```

**If you must use an Array**

You need some form of a placeholder to keep your position within the array.

```
int position = 0;
```

You also need an input mechanism, that we will assume is `scanner`.

```
studentNamesArray[position++] = scanner.readLine();
```

What this will do is return the value of `position` (which at the moment is 0) and then increment it, making it `1`.

This will prevent it from overwriting names in the array because the index is always increasing directly after assignment.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted to non OO methods, however I will vote your answer up for anyone else that might find this useful as I agree it is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't thoroughly read your post but I have the feeling that it would be better to use a `List<String>` and add the student names as they are entered. Afterwards you just query the list for its size to get the number of names entered.

It's something like this pseudo code:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

while( names.size() < 10 ) {
  String name = //ask the user for another name
  if( meetsCondition(name) ) {
    names.add( name );
  } 

  //maybe also add an option to enter less names, e.g. ask the user
  if( userWantsToFinish() ) {
    break;
  }
}

int numNamesEntered = names.size();
```

If you *really* have to use an array, replace the list with the array and track the number of names separately:

```
String[] names = new String[10]; 
int numNamesEntered = 0 ;    

while( numNamesEntered < names.length ) {
  String name = //ask the user for another name
  if( meetsCondition(name) ) {
    names[numNamesEntered] = name;
    numNamesEntered++; //for clarity, could also be done in the line above
  } 

  //maybe also add an option to enter less names, e.g. ask the user
  if( userWantsToFinish() ) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ArrayList` and check the size that way. That way, you're not stuck with null values if user stops before 10.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
String name;

while (names.size() < 10) {
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("no") break;

    System.out.println("Enter an name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();

    names.add(name);

    System.out.println("Would you like to continue?");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

}
```

Comment: `while (true && names.size() < 10)` there's no need for that `true` here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I'll do your homework!

Coded in this text box -- i'll leave fixing it for you.

```
public class HomeWorkAssignment {

    public static void main( String... args ) throws Exception {

        String arrayOfNames = new ArrayOfNames[10];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)

        for( int i = 0; i < arrayOfNames.length; i++ ) {
            if( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
                String studentName = scanner.nextLine();
                arrayOfNames[i] = studentName;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.printf( "Names: %s", Arrays.toString( studentNames ) )

    }

}
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking, after one name has been entered I want it to exit the function which brings the user back to a menu. Only if they select to enter a name again I want them to be taken back into that function and the name to be written to the next index

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, what you want to do is about the following:

```
if (containsName(studentNamesArray, studentName) == false) {
  addStudent(studentNamesArray, studentName);
}
```

Besides that this could be easily solved with a Java [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) like this:

```
studentSet.add(studentName); // automatically ignores duplicates
```

all you need to do for the first code part is to write the functions `containsName` and `addStudent`

```
boolean containsName(String[] studentNamesArray, String studentName) {
  for (int i = 0; i < studentNamesArray.length; ++i) { // specialized while loop over all array elements
    if (studentName.equals(studentNamesArray[i])) { // use equals for String comparison! This will as well not match on "null"
      return true; // we found a match
    }
  }
  return false; // no match was found
}
```

And

```
void addStudent(String[] studentNamesArray, String studentName) {
  int i = 0; 
  while ((studentNamesArray[i] != null) && // this student entry is already filled by someone else
         (i < studentNamesArray.length)) { // we are still within the array bounds
    ++i;
  }
  if (i < studentNamesArray.length) { // is i still within the array bounds?
    studentNamesArray[i] = studentName; // add the student
  } else {
    // we have too many students. What to do now?
  }
}
```

There are several things not checked in this code:

- What if there are more students than the size of the array?
- What if studentName is `null`?

This approach to writing code is called [Top-down approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design) and makes coding much easier, if you know the general program logic, but not yet the details.

**Edit:** The full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  static boolean containsName(String[] studentNamesArray, String studentName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < studentNamesArray.length; ++i) { // specialized while loop over all array elements
      if (studentName.equals(studentNamesArray[i])) { // use equals for String comparison! This will as well not match on "null"
        return true; // we found a match
      }
    }
    return false; // no match was found
  }

  static void addStudent(String[] studentNamesArray, String studentName) {
    int i = 0;
    while ((studentNamesArray[i] != null) && // this student entry is already filled by someone else
            (i < studentNamesArray.length)) { // we are still within the array bounds
      ++i;
    }
    if (i < studentNamesArray.length) { // is i still within the array bounds?
      studentNamesArray[i] = studentName; // add the student
    } else {
      // we have too many students. What to do now?
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] studentNamesArray = new String[10];
    String studentName;

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
      System.out.println("Please insert your name:");
      studentName = scanner.nextLine();
      if (studentName.length() > 0) {
        if (containsName(studentNamesArray, studentName) == false) {
          addStudent(studentNamesArray, studentName);
          System.out.println(studentName + " added.");
        } else {
          System.out.println(studentName + " was already in the list.");
        }
      }
    } while (studentName.length() > 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < studentNamesArray.length; ++i) {
      System.out.println("Student #" + i + ": " + studentNamesArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Using sample input, I get the following:

```
Please insert your name:
Two
Two added.
Please insert your name:
Test
Test added.
Please insert your name:
Test
Test was already in the list.
Please insert your name:
test
test added.
Please insert your name:
test
test was already in the list.
Please insert your name:

Student #0: Two
Student #1: Test
Student #2: test
Student #3: null
Student #4: null
Student #5: null
Student #6: null
Student #7: null
Student #8: null
Student #9: null
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your solution but it still seems to be overwriting the first index in the array.

Comment: It seems `containsName` is always returning `false`

Comment: Please compare my full code with yours. The functions are working fine, so there has to be an error in your implementation.